# Counting filled rows in Datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I'm trying to count the filled rows in datagridview by a function.
This function contains 2 parameters, 1st one is the count of columns which i want to be filled and 2nd one the count of rows of datagridview.
I tried this code:

```
Function dgvAggregate(ByVal colNum As Integer, ByVal dgvcount As Integer)
    Dim x As Integer = 0
    For i As Integer = 0 To dgvcount - 1
        For j As Integer = 0 To colNum
            If Not (dg.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value = Nothing) Then
                x += 1

            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    Return x
End Function  

Private Sub Button6_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click
    MsgBox(dgvAggregate(2, dg.Rows.Count))
End Sub
```

But this code return the number of cells that has a value!
How can i count only rows depending on the columns count entered by user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are incrementing *x* for every cell which has a value.  You need to be testing and incrementing on a row basis, in your loop over *i*.

You need to set a flag at the start of the loop and then check for any columns with *nothing*, updating the flag if you find some.  If the flag hasn't been updated, then increment *x*.

```
Function dgvAggregate(ByVal colNum As Integer, ByVal dgvcount As Integer)
    Dim x As Integer = 0
    Dim emptyColumns as Integer = 0

    For i As Integer = 0 To dgvcount - 1
        emptyColumns = 0
        For j As Integer = 0 To colNum
            If dg.Rows(j).Cells(i).Value = Nothing Then
                emptyColumns += 1
            End If
        Next j
        If emptyColumns = 0 Then
            x += 1
        End If
    Next i

    Return x
End Function  

Private Sub Button6_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click
    MsgBox(dgvAggregate(2, dg.Rows.Count))
 End Sub
```

Comment: flag?!!, how is that?

Comment: If you like the answer and it works for you, please accept the answer

Comment: You should be able to accept the answer since it is your question.  I think there should be a checkmark next to the vote total